# Metal Multisample not resolving

Tags: metal

I've written some simple multisampled rendering in Metal. It's just drawing a single solid colored quad. After rendering I read the contents of the resolve texture. This works on Intel and M1 but fails on AMD and NVidia.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Metal's API Validation doesn't complain about anything :(

```
//
//  Renderer.swift
//  metaltest
//
import Foundation
import Metal
import MetalKit

class Renderer : NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {

    let device: MTLDevice
    let commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue
    let pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState
    let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer
    let texture: MTLTexture
    let resolveTexture: MTLTexture
    let width = 16;
    let height = 16;

    //let samplerState: MTLSamplerState
    var frameCount: Int = 0
    
    // This is the initializer for the Renderer class.
    // We will need access to the mtkView later, so we add it as a parameter here.
    init?(mtkView: MTKView) {
        device = mtkView.device!
        mtkView.framebufferOnly = true

        commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!

        // Create the Render Pipeline
        do {
            pipelineState = try Renderer.buildRenderPipelineWith(device: device, metalKitView: mtkView)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to compile render pipeline state: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
        
        // Create our vertex data
        let vertices = [
            Vertex(pos: [-1, -1]),
            Vertex(pos: [ 1, -1]),
            Vertex(pos: [-1,  1]),
            
            Vertex(pos: [-1,  1]),
            Vertex(pos: [ 1, -1]),
            Vertex(pos: [ 1,  1]),
        ]
        // And copy it to a Metal buffer...
        vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: vertices.count * MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride, options: [])!

        print("texture size: width: \(width), height: \(height)")
        let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(
                  pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat.rgba8Unorm,
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  mipmapped: false)
        textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4
        textureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget]
        textureDescriptor.textureType = .type2DMultisample
        textureDescriptor.storageMode = .private

        
        texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)!

        let resolveTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(
                  pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat.rgba8Unorm,
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  mipmapped: false)
        resolveTextureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget]

        resolveTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: resolveTextureDescriptor)!
    }
    
    // Create our custom rendering pipeline, which loads shaders using `device`, and outputs to the format of `metalKitView`
    class func buildRenderPipelineWith(device: MTLDevice, metalKitView: MTKView) throws -> MTLRenderPipelineState {
        // Create a new pipeline descriptor
        let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        
        // Setup the shaders in the pipeline
        let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()
        pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "vertexShader")
        pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "fragmentShader")

        // Setup the output pixel format to match the pixel format of the metal kit view
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.rgba8Unorm;
        pipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = 4;
        
        // Compile the configured pipeline descriptor to a pipeline state object
        return try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
    }
    
    // mtkView will automatically call this function
    // whenever it wants new content to be rendered.
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { return }
        let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor(); // view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }

        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture;
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 1, 1, 1)
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].resolveTexture = resolveTexture;
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .storeAndMultisampleResolve

        guard let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { return }

        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)

        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 6)
        renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

        let pixelCount = width * height
        let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)

        var pixels = Array<UInt8>(repeating: UInt8(0), count: pixelCount * 4)
        resolveTexture.getBytes(
            &pixels,
            bytesPerRow: width * 4,
            from: region,
            mipmapLevel: 0);
        print("dest size: width: \(width), height: \(height)")
        print("Top Left    : \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[0])), \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[1])), \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[2])), \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[3])), expected: (0x80, 0x99, 0xB2, 0xCC)")
        let offset = width * height * 4 - 4;
        print("Bottom Right: \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[offset])), \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[offset + 1])), \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[offset + 2])), \(String(format:"%02X", pixels[offset + 3])), expected: (0x80, 0x99, 0xB2, 0xCC)")
        exit(0)
    }

    // mtkView will automatically call this function
    // whenever the size of the view changes (such as resizing the window).
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

    }
}
```

Shader

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include "ShaderDefinitions.h"
using namespace metal;

struct VertexOut {
    float4 pos [[position]];
};

vertex VertexOut vertexShader(const device Vertex *vertexArray [[buffer(0)]], unsigned int vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    Vertex in = vertexArray[vid];
 
    VertexOut out;

    out.pos = float4(in.pos.xy, 0, 1);

    return out;
    
}

fragment float4 fragmentShader()
{
    return float4(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8);
}
```

ShaderDefinitions.h

```
#ifndef ShaderDefinitions_h
#define ShaderDefinitions_h

#include <simd/simd.h>

struct Vertex {
    vector_float2 pos;
};

#endif /* ShaderDefinitions_h */
```

The output I expect is:

```
Top Left    : 80, 99, B2, CC, expected: (0x80, 0x99, 0xB2, 0xCC)
Bottom Right: 80, 99, B2, CC, expected: (0x80, 0x99, 0xB2, 0xCC)
```

Which is what I get on Intel and M1 but on AMD and NVidia I get

```
Top Left    : 00, 00, 00, 00, expected: (0x80, 0x99, 0xB2, 0xCC)
Bottom Right: 00, 00, 00, 00, expected: (0x80, 0x99, 0xB2, 0xCC)
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Intel**, **Apple M1**] - *unified memory model*

[**Nvidia**, **AMD**] - *discrete memory model*

[Understand the Private Mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/setting_resource_storage_modes/choosing_a_resource_storage_mode_in_macos?language=objc)

> A resource with a MTLStorageModePrivate mode is accessible only to the
> GPU. In a unified memory model, this resource resides in system
> memory. In a discrete memory model, it resides in video memory.

[image]

Use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400773-copy) implementation to copy texture data from a **Private Texture** to a **Shared Buffer**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed to call synchronize in order to make the data available to the GPU

```
guard let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder() else { return }
blitEncoder.synchronize(texture: resolveTexture, slice: 0, level: 0);
blitEncoder.endEncoding();
```

Inserting that code before `commandBuffer.commit()` in the code from the question solved the issue